# Rails link_to object interpolation with url instead of path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have two models, say `User` and `Group`

I know I can access the show action to each object with the different solutions:

```
# PATH
link_to user.name, user_path(user)
link_to group.name, group_path(group)

# URL
link_to user.name, user_url(user)
link_to group.name, group_url(group)
```

But Rails' magic occurs when

```
# PATH
link_to user.name, user_path(user)
link_to group.name, group_path(group)
# is equivalent to
# PATH
link_to user.name, user
link_to group.name, group
```

Is there a way I can interpolate to get the url?

I could write something like this:

```
link_to user.name, send("#{user.class.name.downcase}_url", user)
```

But is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Can you give clarification about why you need to use the URL rather than the path? One possible approach is to use something like what inherited_resources does. It creates resource_path and resource_url helpers that return the path/url for the appropriate object given the context.

Comment: I need resource_url helper because it will be sent in an email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

url_for calls polymorphic_path() with the object you pass when you pass in an ActiveRecord (as well as some other cases). you can use polymorphic_url instead to get what you want.

```
link_to object.name, polymorphic_url(object)
```

Comment: Wonderful! I'll check the source code of this method!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to tell link_to to use the url when you pass only the model in. You'll have to stick to `user_url`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to